# Strange behavior of abs(x) in PGF Plots

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}    [
        axis lines = {center},
        width = {0.6\linewidth},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ytick distance = {2},
        minor y tick num = {1}
        ]

    \addplot    [
                mark = none, domain= -3:4
                ]
                {abs(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

That produces the following image, notice close to `x=0`that there's a strange "break" on the function's plot. What could be the cause? How do I get rid of that?

[image: Weird break next to x = 0]

I noticed the problem also happens if I use a function with conditions say:

`{x<0 ? -x+5 : x-2};`

On the area near `x=0` a weird break happens.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not strange, consider where the function value is calculated, by setting `mark = x`:

[image]

The default number of samples is 25, and 25 samples from -3 to 4 gives one sample at `-0.0833` and the next at `0.20833`. The asymmetry causes the problem you see.

If you set the number of samples and the domain such that you get a sample exactly at zero, you should be fine. With the domain `-3:4`, `samples=8` or `samples=15` for example will give you a sample at zero. Alternatively, for this specific case you can set `samples at={-3,0,4}`:

[image]

## Complete code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}    [
        axis lines = {center},
        width = {0.6\linewidth},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ytick distance = {2},
        minor y tick num = {1}
        ]

    \addplot    [
                mark = none, samples at={-3,0,4}
                ]
                {abs(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My apologies for not accepting the answer earlier, I completely forgot. It's set now :)

Comment: There is also a big bug in pgfplots in the first picture. Please see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630075/severe-bug-in-pgfplots-in-certains-circonstances-on-y-axis-the-distance-from